# Acrobat displays corrupted PDF documents that conatin xref streams, after preparation for signing

Tags: javascript, pdf

We are working on a webapp that signs PDF documents. The workflow looks something like this:

1. PDF is uploaded to the server
2. Acroform is appended, and the necessary annotations are added, along with other XObjects required to make a signature
3. Old Xref Tables/Streams are removed
4. New Xref Tables/Streams are generated
5. Digest is calculated over the part of the document marked by the ByteRange
6. Digest is send to the backend for signing
7. The resulting signature is embedded into the PDF on the client

The PDFs that use XRef tables are signed fine. However, we also needed to add the possibility to sign the PDFs that use XRef Streams. I know that in steps 3 and 4 it may be wiser to make incremental updates instead of removing all of the XRef Streams/Tables and making a new one. However, since we already had a flow like that working for the XRef Tables, we decided to keep the consistency for now, and do it same for the XRef Streams.

It seems that there are some problems with the PDFs where XRef Streams are used. The old ones are removed fine, and also the new one is generated and on the first view looks fine. However, when I try to open the document in Acrobat I get a message that the document is corrupted.

Here's the relevant part of the code that creates XRef Stream in case XRef streams are used:

```
{
.
.
.
    const xrefStream = this.createXrefStream(pdf.xref.entries);
                const ids = pdf.xref.topDict.map.ID;
                const info = pdf.xref.topDict.map.Info;
                const rootEntry = pdf.xref.topDict.map.Root;
                const xrefStreamObj = '\n' + xrefStreamEntry + ' 0 obj\n' +
                    '<</DecodeParms' + '\n' +
                    '<</Columns 5/Predictor 12>>' + '\n' +
                    '/Filter/FlateDecode' + '\n' +
                    '/ID[<' + this.strHex(ids[0]) + '><' + this.strHex(ids[1]) + '>]' + '\n' +
                    '/Info ' + info.num + ' ' + info.gen + ' R' + '\n' +
                    '/Length ' + xrefStream.length + '\n' +
                    '/Root ' + rootEntry.num + ' ' + rootEntry.gen + ' R' + '\n' +
                    '/Size ' + (xrefStreamEntry + 1) + '\n' +
                    '/Type/XRef' + '\n' +
                    '/W[1 3 1]>>' + '\n' +
                    'stream\n' +
                    xrefStream + '\n' +
                    'endstream' + '\n' +
                    'startxref' + '\n' +
                    (array.length + 1) + '\n' +
                    '%%EOF';
    
                array = this.insertIntoArray(array, array.length, xrefStreamObj);
.
.
.
}

private createXrefStream(entries: any) {
        const xrefStreamData = [];
        entries.forEach((entry, i) => {
            xrefStreamData[i] = [];
            if (entry.free) {
                xrefStreamData[i][0] = 0;
                xrefStreamData[i][1] = entry.offset;
                xrefStreamData[i][2] = entry.gen;
            } else if (entry.uncompressed) {
                xrefStreamData[i][0] = 1;
                xrefStreamData[i][1] = entry.offset;
                xrefStreamData[i][2] = entry.gen;
            } else {
                xrefStreamData[i][0] = 2;
                xrefStreamData[i][1] = entry.offset;
                xrefStreamData[i][2] = entry.gen;
            }
        });

        const xrefStreamBytes = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < xrefStreamData.length; i++) {
            xrefStreamBytes[i] = [];
            xrefStreamBytes[i][0] = xrefStreamData[i][0];
            xrefStreamBytes[i][4] = xrefStreamData[i][2];

            let hexOffset = xrefStreamData[i][1].toString(16);
            const hexOffsetLength = hexOffset.length;

            for (let j = 0; j < 6 - hexOffsetLength; j++) {
                hexOffset = '0' + hexOffset;
            }

            const offsetBytes = this.hex2Uint8Array(hexOffset);
            for (let j = 0; j < offsetBytes.length; j++) {
                xrefStreamBytes[i][j + 1] = offsetBytes[j];
            }
        }

        xrefStreamBytes[-1] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < xrefStreamBytes.length; i++) {
            xrefStreamBytes[-1][i] = 0;
        }

        const encodedXrerStreamBytes = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < xrefStreamBytes.length; i++) {
            encodedXrerStreamBytes[i] = [];
            encodedXrerStreamBytes[i][0] = 2;
            for (let j = 1; j < xrefStreamBytes[i].length; j++) {
                encodedXrerStreamBytes[i][j] = Math.abs(xrefStreamBytes[i][j - 1] - xrefStreamBytes[i - 1][j - 1]);
            }
        }

        const linearXrefStreamBytes = [];
        let counter = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < encodedXrerStreamBytes.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < encodedXrerStreamBytes[i].length; j++) {
                linearXrefStreamBytes[counter] = encodedXrerStreamBytes[i][j];
                counter++;
            }
        }

        const deflated = pako.deflate(linearXrefStreamBytes);
        const xrefStream = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(deflated);

        return xrefStream;

    }
```

Here's a signed PDF that's making problems [here](https://ufile.io/iqk2el9c). I don't know what to do, debugging PDFs is hard since I can't get any info about the errors.

**EDIT:** There was an error in size attribute in the xref stream dictionary. The size was wrongly calculated. The actual number of xref entries in the xref stream is 10596 which seems ok, as it's the greatest object number in the given pdf. Unfortunately, that wasn't the only problem and I Acrobat still sees the PDF as corrupted. There is probably some error in the xref stream itself as @mkl has suggested but I can't find it.

**EDIT2:**I found another error in my xref stream. I updated the code with the corrected version and also the PDF file. However, Acrobat still sees the pdf as corrupted

**EDIT3:** I found another problem. The Columns value in my DecodeParams dictionary was set to 4, and the W value was [1 3 1] meaning that each row (each xref entry) has 1+3+1 = 5 bytes. I corrected this, but I still get the error. I updated the link.

Comment: At first glance the cross reference stream did not look correctly processed. Unfortunately I'm only at a smart phone currently, so i cannot analyze in depth.

Comment: Ah, and there is a serious problem in your cross reference data to start with: The PDF has object numbers up into the 10xxx but in your cross reference stream you only claim a **Size** of 2254, so you apparently dropped more than 8000 entries... This looks like conceptual issues in your cross reference reading or managing code.

Comment: There was indeed an error in the size calculation, however, it was only an error in size calculation and the actual number of xref entries that were read from the old xref streams and encoded in the new xref streams is 10596. I corrected the size calculation but I still get a parsing error in Acrobat

Comment: Your xref stream data is completely broken. Already the header checksum check fails. I don't know the JavaScript classes at all but if I had to guess, I'd say that applying `TextDecoder('utf-8').decode` to the `pako.deflate` result in `deflated` actually utterly destroys the compressed data.